# Why is Eclipse not displaying project 'correctly' anymore?

Tags: android, eclipse

I only have on project and in it, the layout of the project has become 'messed up.' See here:

[image]

The dot files are now visible. The src folder is not collapsed anymore... that is to say, the empty folder are now not showing up as one folder anymore.

What the heck did I do here?

Comment: your source isn't a source folder...

Comment: This question is really better off on SO as it deals with implementation and programming tools. Please don't re-ask this there as it can be migrated. A good rule to follow is if your question has you in front of your IDE it belongs on SO. If it has you in front of a whiteboard it belongs on Programmers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've changed from Java perspective to Java EE perspective or what *ratchet freak* said :).